# UIImageView Handles drag system

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, draggable

I have an image, and through a drag, depending  if I touch on left or right, it expands. such as, for example, the editing software video / audio handles.
My problem is, strangely, it works on the left (with a position/size system), but not on the right. On the right, when I drag the image expands exponentially.

This is the code I use:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == handlesImg) {

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        locationOne = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
       //Left
       if (locationOne.x < 12) {

            dragTimeLineInt = 1;

        }
       //Right
       else if (locationOne.x >  handlesImg.frame.size.width -12) {

        dragTimeLineInt = 2;


       }
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:handlesImg];
    CGRect frame = [handlesImg frame];

    float xSize = frame.size.width;
    float xPos = frame.origin.x;

    switch (dragTimeLineInt) {
        case 1: //Left

        xSize -= pt.x -locationOne.x;
        xPos += pt.x - locationOne.x;
        [handlesImg setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, xSize, 40)];

        break;

    case 2: //Right
        xSize += pt.x -locationOne.x;
        [handlesImg setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, xSize, 40)];

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps... but looking at your second case statement in the `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` method, I noticed that you aren't updating the `xPos` as you did in the first case statement. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sure, don't increase the position x, because pulling on the right, the frame must remain stopped on the left anchor point